# If you lose healing surges, will they count for Strongheart Tattoo

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, healing

The *Strongheart Tattoo* [DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=item&id=2681) has the benefit:

> When you spend a healing surge, you regain extra hit points equal to the number of healing surges you have spent since your last extended rest.

Will this apply, e.g. when you've lost healing surge(s) as a result of failures in a Skill Challenge ?

One side of our discussion is... I have X healing surges, so my *Strongheart*Tattoo` bonus is simply equal to ... " X - ( current number of healing surges )" no matter how I've "spent" them.

The other side is the ones you've lost have not actually been "spent".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No.**

Spending a healing surge is a specific action. Losing a healing surge is a different specific action. They are not the same thing.

Spending a healing surge usually results in a benefit to you; this is an additional rider on that benefit.

Losing a healing surge is not a voluntary action and is typically mandated by a failure of a skill challenge.

Losing does not count as spending.

Comment: That was my thinking, but it was useful to get another unbiased opinion